# Handle two versions of GDAL

Tags: gdal, ubuntu, linux, shell, ubuntugis

I want to use two different GDAL versions on my Ubuntu 16.04. I installed GDAL via the UbuntuGIS ppa and via anaconda. My GDAL for python works fine, but when I want to use gdal_translate via the shell to convert a .jp2 to .tif the following error occurs:

> ERROR 4: `/media/lastro/.../L2A_T32ULB_20170430T103021_AOT_10m.jp2'
>   not recognized as a supported file format

When I remove anaconda and have only gdal from the ubuntuGIS ppa installed then it works, but when I then install anaconda with the gdal binding the same error occurs.

Does someone know a workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You should set your environment variable to the ubuntuGIS GDAL, as this will have the needed file support. You should have a PATH variable set to the correct GDAL.

First check with the command `which -a gdal-config` where your GDAL versions are installed. The -a checks for several installations. There should be two in your case. Then check with `echo $PATH` if you have a PATH set to your installation folder of your Ubuntugis-GDAL. If not you need to set the variable with `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/directory_of_ubuntugis_gdal`.

Comment: What if I need to uninstall one of them? I have installed gdal-1.10.1 and gdal-2.0.1 from source and I woud like to uninstall gdal-1.10.1, in order to install sf package in r.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible as noted in this post [Multiple versions of GDAL (32bit and 64bit) on same machine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/44194/35779).

I would count on it being an issue during installation as where the GDAL is being read from and install location perhaps.